# Displaying data to Modal from Database - Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

when i click the data from filtered table, the modal will display, but there is no data to show ..

this is my code ..

this code is to display all the data from database ..

```
            <tbody id="cdr_control_holder">
            <?php foreach ($cdr_table as $cdr) { ?>
              <tr class="historylist" data-callsid="<?php echo $cdr->xcallsid; ?>" style="cursor: pointer; ">
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->user_firstname." ".$cdr->user_lastname; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->talk_time; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->aftertalk_time; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->hold_time; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->total_time; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->date_created; ?></td>
                  <td class="numClass"><?php echo $cdr->phone_number; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $cdr->classification; ?></td>
              </tr>
            <?php }?>
            </tbody>
```

and this is my AJAX code ..

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>tenant/view_report/filter_date",
                    method: "POST",
                    data:{globoy_daterange:from, globoy_daterange2:to},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#cdr_control_holder').html('');
                            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                                html = '';
                                html+= '<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCallDetails" class="historylist" data-callsid="'+data[i]['xcallsid']+'" style="cursor:pointer;">';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['user_firstname']+' '+data[i]['user_lastname']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['talk_time']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['aftertalk_time']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['hold_time']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['total_time']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['date_created']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td class="numClass">'+data[i]['phone_number']+'</td>';
                                html+= '<td>'+data[i]['classification']+'</td>';
                                html+= '</tr>';
                                $('#cdr_control_holder').append(html);
                            }
                        }
                });
```

i cant figure out whats wrong .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a new version of jQuery, you cant use success() method. Instead, try done().

Take a look at the new documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )

.done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After this...

```
success:function(data){
```

Please add this...

```
console.log(data);
```

Re-run the code.

Then please open the console in your browser and copy and paste the result from the console in a reply here.

This will help us to resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

@WebCode.ie

i cant reply to your comment ..

so here's the screenshot of the console.log(data) that you've requested

[image: console.log(data)]